# executeFetchRequest exits current method

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm experiencing a strange problem with Core Data. Target is iOS 5.0

This line of code:

```
   NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

exits the current method. No code is executed after that line. The app doesn't crash. No exceptions are thrown. This happens occasionally, not every time.

As I step through code and hit that line, it just returns from the current method.

Any hints, clues, etc?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try to pause the execution and see what's happening in the call stack?

Comment: the error I tend to do: be sure error is nil

Comment: Don't know if you already have introspect the error. Otherwise it dpends of many things, for example if this execute within a separate thread, the thread get killed and you never get informed. And the app doesn't crash.

Comment: @KyrDunenkoff I tried to pause the execution and everything looks normal, until I call executeFetchRequest. Then, after that call, the method immediately returns. Code doesn't follow the normal execution path. The app doesn't crash though. That's what's strange.

Comment: @Leonardo This is executed on a separate thread. It does look like it gets killed and I'm not informed. What you said makes sense, but I'm clueless on how to prevent it from happening.

Comment: @JeromeDiaz error is indeed nil. I've been bitten by that before.

Comment: so have I, so have I ;)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comment, the fetch is probably executed on a separate thread. That explains why the app doesn't crash.

Without seeing the code, the crash maybe caused by a wrong fetch request, probably in its syntax.

Try to put a breakpoint and at least print the statement, for example with `po request` in the console, or `NSLog(yourStatament)` you should be able to see the whole statement. Have a look if something in there is *nil*.

Also, I see you are using `self` in your execute fetch. If this is a separate thread I would probably take a strong reference to `self` to let the main thread release resources. But this just a guess.